# How to use 'more' to check possible file types for 'file'

Tags: unix

I don't understand what this question is asking: "Use `more` to check some possible file types that can be recognized with the `file` command by peeking in the configuration file `/etc/magic`."

- `more` is used to display files that are too long to fit on the page.
- `file` checks the type of the file.
- `/etc/magic` has two comments in it. thats it.

I am reading the book "Sams Teach Yourself Unix in 24 Hours" eBook and this question came up.

Comment: so you have tried using `file` on numerous types of files? Did you get a reasonable response on compiled executables, vs executable shell scripts versus non-executable text files vs pdf and other proprietary files? "`/etc/magic` has two comments", what only 2 lines altogether in the file? That's unusual. Or are you expecting the file to be fully commented? Finally, edit you Q to include output of `uname -srv`. It sounds like this instruction is about getting you used to inspecting files with the available tools and to  understand why a compiled executable won't have much to look atEtc GoodLuck

Comment: @shelter Ya I used 'cat' on /etc/magic and only two commented lines showed up. Anyways, I think you are right. thanks!

Comment: except from this i can also suggest you the Teach Yourself UNIX in 24 Hours by Dave Taylor and James C. Armstrong Jr., SAMS PUBLISHING.